# why my background is going in front of my text?

Tags: html, css

why my background is going in front of my text?

so I have .html and .css file like this
I've tried postion relative, absolute, fixed but the output still not what I want.

```css
    .main-main-container{
     position:absolute;
     display: grid;
     height: 100vh;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     
    }
    
    .main-container{
     display: grid;
     //grid-template-rows: minmax(20%,auto) auto minmax(20%,auto) minmax(10%,auto);
     grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr 1fr 40px ;
     grid-gap: 0.5em;
     
    }
    
    /*
    @keyframes sliding-background{
     0%{
      background-image: url(../images/Desert.jpg);
     }
     25%{
      background-image: url(../images/Hydrangeas.jpg);
     }
     50%{
      background-image: url(../images/Jellyfish.jpg);
     }
     75%{
      background-image: url(../images/Lighthouse.jpg);
     }
     100%{
      background-image: url(../images/Penguins.jpg);
     }
    
    }
    */
    
    .main-container > figure {
     animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center center;
     color: transparent;
     height: 100%;
     left: 0px;
     opacity: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 0;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
    }
    .main-container > figure:nth-child(1) {
     background-image: url('../images/Desert.jpg');
    }
    .main-container > figure:nth-child(2) {
     animation-delay: 6s;
     background-image: url('../images/Hydrangeas.jpg');
    }
    .main-container > figure:nth-child(3) {
     animation-delay: 12s;
     background-image: url('../images/Jellyfish.jpg');
    }
    .main-container > figure:nth-child(4) {
     animation-delay: 18s;
     background-image: url('../images/Lighthouse.jpg');
    }
    .main-container > figure:nth-child(5) {
     animation-delay: 24s;
     background-image: url('../images/Penguins.jpg');
    }
    
    @keyframes imageAnimation {
     0% {
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      opacity: 0;
     }
     8% {
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      opacity: 1;
     }
     17% {
      opacity: 1
     }
     25% {
      opacity: 0
     }
     100% {
      opacity: 0
     }
    }
    
    .header-container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
     //background: red;
     
    }
    
    .content-container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
     //background: yellow;
    }
    
    .subcontent-container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
     //background: green;
    }
    
    .header-container > div,
    .content-container > div,
    .subcontent-container > div{
     border: #222 1px solid;
    }
    
    .content{
     //background: green;
    }
    
    .sub-content{
     //background: yellow
    }
    
    .footer-container{
     //background: pink;
     border: #222 1px solid;
     
    }
```

```html
    <body class="main-main-container">
     <div class="main-container">
      <figure></figure>
      <figure></figure>
      <figure></figure>
      <figure></figure>
      <figure></figure>
      <div class="header-container">
       <div class="header-left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       </div>
       <div class="header-center">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, quis ducimus sed in exercitationem quae, molestias placeat eius eveniet molestiae repellendus animi dignissimos, non nostrum facere id iste fugit aspernatur est perferendis? Eaque tempora nesciunt deleniti voluptatem ad quisquam voluptatum.
       </div>
       <div class="header-right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
       <div class="content-left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem amet maiores, voluptatem quibusdam et veritatis repellendus reiciendis dolor facilis assumenda.
       </div>
       <div class="content-center">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem amet maiores, voluptatem quibusdam et veritatis repellendus reiciendis dolor facilis assumenda.
       </div>
       <div class="content-right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem amet maiores, voluptatem quibusdam et veritatis repellendus reiciendis dolor facilis assumenda.
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="subcontent-container">
       <div class="subcontent-left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, nam.
       </div>
       <div class="subcontent-center">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, nam.
       </div>
       <div class="subcontent-right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, nam.
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-container">
       <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      </body>
```

what I want is my sliding-figure is in the back of my text so its become my background image not replacing my text in front of it.

Comment: Hey Furlong, can you provide css/main.css

Comment: yes, I just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.main-container > figure{
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[working Fiddle](https://codepen.io/pratik-sangami/pen/KKPRjag)

**I think this will make it work.**

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-container > figure {
    animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -3;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Update the CSS Class as above...Its because of Z-index